Why can't Electron load the static file for Next.js?
The out/index.html load and related files (out/_next) generated by Next.js using the static build files of Electron and Next.js are not being loaded.
The actual project structure looks like this

The Electron code is simple and looks like this.
const createWindow = () => {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720
    });

    // dev tools
    window.webContents.openDevTools();

    window.loadFile('./frontend/out/index.html');
}

// when started
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
});

I wanted to customize the protocol, and tried to use protocol.handle() or modify the file protocol itself, but failed.
How can I modify my code to make it work?
